# Gorilla mux subdomain

Tags: google-app-engine, go, gorilla

How can I add a subdomain using gorilla mux and do something like:

```
http://api.localhost:8080/
```

I have tried

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/path", method).Methods("POST").Host("api.example.com")
```

But I don't want to pass the domain, because I need to change the domain each time I upload it to app engine, plus I think the above code will not work using the app engine framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a [subrouter](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Route.Subrouter) for the subdomain:

```
s := r.Host("www.domain.com").Subrouter()
s.HandleFunc("/path", method).Methods("POST")
```